# Python code interaction with a QGIS line layer

Tags: pyqgis

I'm writing a python code to manipulate the attribute table of a QGIS layer.
To be specific, I have a column with cells filled in for example:

- the car is blue
- the car is blue
- the bike is red

The code should unpack the cell with the help of an array and count how many times the same sentence is present and then replace the cell with:

- 2 x the car is blue
- the motorbike is red.

Up to now I've written this, but it isn't working

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingUtils, QgsProject

layer = QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString('OUTPUT_trassenplan')

if layer is None:
    print("Impossibile caricare il layer temporaneo!") else:    
    idx = layer.fields().indexFromName('text 3')
  
    row_frequencies = {}
    
    for feature in layer.getFeatures():        
        text_value = feature.attributes()[idx]
        
        if text_value:            
            lines = text_value.split('\n')
            for line in lines:
                row_frequencies[line] = row_frequencies.get(line, 0) + 1
    
    with edit(layer):
        for feature in layer.getFeatures():            
            text_value = feature.attributes()[idx]
            
            if text_value:              
                lines = text_value.split('\n')
                               
                new_lines = []
                for line in lines:
                    if row_frequencies[line] > 1:
                        new_lines.append(f"{line} ({row_frequencies[line]})")
                    else:
                        new_lines.append(line)                
                
                feature.setAttribute(idx, '\n'.join(new_lines))
                layer.updateFeature(feature)

QgsProject.instance().write()#
```

What should I do?

Comment: Can you share a piece of your data for testing purposes ?

Comment: I dont understand. Can you add an example of your data and the column you want to calculate? You have one column and row with the value 
`the car is blue the car is blue the bike is red`? With what delimiter? What is the array you are going to use the "unpack it"?